# Вертикальное центрирование CSS

Tags: html, css

Нужно сделать так чтобы элемент был вертикально по центру, а слева отступ всего в 64px c использованием flex.

```
<div class="page">> 
       <h1>Heading</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* обнуление стилей */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page {
  /*  скорее всего ваша проблема здесь, ведь для работы flex надо указать размер */
  height: 100vh; 
  width: 100vw;
  
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* расположение вертикально по центру */
  padding-left: 64px; /* отступ на 64 */
}
```

```html
<div class="page">>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Отправка в никуда это плохой тон. Или ссылку дайте, где почитать про конкретный кейс, другим тоже будет интересно. [Почитайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct)

Comment: Да, вы правы. Я думаю, стоит почитать вот здесь: https://clck.ru/337WUF